# How Can I Convert a String to Hours, Minutes, and Seconds in R?

Tags: r, string

I want to change the values in a time variable so from a string to time. I have looked up how to do this and have not found results. I have not been able to find a solution for a string formatted in this way:

ex: 57M 13S
ex: 34S
ex: 54H 3M 23S

I would like it to be formatted as:

ex: 57:13:00
ex: 00:00:34
ex: 54:03:23

What can be done so that I can change the formatting in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the first element is `minutes, seconds`, convert the string to `period` class and use `hms`

```
library(period)
hms::hms(as.period(str1))
00:57:13
00:00:34
54:03:23
```

### data

```
str1 <- c("57M 13S", "34S", "54H 3M 23S")
```